# How to create table with GUID / Autogenerate key in DataBricks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am working on AWS databricks version of apache spark. Would like to create table schema's with primary key and foreign keys. I believe GUID or Autogenerate key is best practice to create any primary key. But how to create on databrick, I am looking for.
Help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 df = spark.table('your table name')

import uuid
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

uuidUdf= udf(lambda : str(uuid.uuid4()),StringType())
df = df.withColumn("id",uuidUdf())
```

Comment: Useful to add: from pyspark.sql.types import StringType